# WordPress uploads pointing to test server

Tags: php, wordpress, path, config

I just took over an older developer and I been trying to make changes to a WordPress page but I just noticed that the uploads are pointing to his test server, so instead of being

`http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/sampleimage.jpg`

all the images and uploads are

`http://172.20.201.879/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/sampleimage.jpg`

What can i change from the back end so it points towards the correct place. The content is there is just the wrong path.

Another question is, can I find out which server was he using? I been trying to update but the server information he gave me is completely wrong.

Comment: did you try changing the site address in settings -> general ?

Comment: That won't change links in db

Comment: If you have access to your db via phpmyadmin or similar, you can run this code `UPDATE \`wp_posts\` SET \`guid\` = REPLACE(\`guid\`, '172.20.201.879' , 'mywebsite.com');` to replace the website address.

Comment: @Eugen I ran the query and it worked, the problem is that the page still is looking for the images at `http://172.20.201.879/...` and not at `http://mywebsite.com/`

Comment: Nevermind I had to change the code in the theme but now finally go it to work, but god knows I have many changes to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Eugen:

If you have access to your db via phpmyadmin or similar, you can run this code UPDATE `wp_posts` SET `guid` = REPLACE(`guid`, '172.20.201.879' , 'mywebsite.com'); to replace the website address.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this: https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Find the old url's: 172.20.201.879/

Replace with: mywebsite.com/

**EDIT**

The reason to use this tool over manual database edits is because of how Wordpress likes to store data in serialized strings. If you edit a serialized string, without changing the additional size delimiter, you will have a corrupt string.